# Modify arguments in self executing function

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, anonymous-function, self-executing-function

I want to be able to modify the arguments passed to a self executing function.

Here is some sample code:

```
var test = 'start';
(function (t) {t = 'end'} )(test);
alert(test) //alerts 'test'
```

And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGurS/). The variable `test` has not changed. How can I alter it, as in pass-by-reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass in an `object`, it is *pass-by-reference*:

```
var test = {
    message: 'start'
};
(function (t) {t.message = 'end'} )(test);
alert(test.message)
```

FYI, `Array` is also *pass-by-reference*.

Comment: It's splitting hairs, but objects and arrays are not pass-by-reference; the reference to the object is passed by value. It seems like a meaningless distinction, and in practical terms it is, but "pass by reference" means something quite specific in programming language design.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! (can accept in 11 minutes)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that (well, **precisely** that) in JavaScript.  You can do something like this, however:

```
 var testBox = { test: "hello" };
 (function(tb) { tb.test = "goodbye"; })(testBox);
 alert(testBox.test); // "goodbye"
```

JavaScript only has pass-by-value in function calls; there's only one corner-case way to have an alias to something like a variable (the `arguments` object and parameters), and it's sufficiently weird to be uninteresting.

That said, object properties are (usually) mutable, so you can pass object references around in cases where you need functions to modify values.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

The best you can do is pass in an object, and then update that object.

```
var test = { state: 'start' };
(function (t) {t.state = 'end'} )(test);
alert(test.state); // 'end'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just passing the value of test variable as an argument to the function. After changing the argument's value you need to assign back to the test variable.

```
var test = 'start';
(function (t){t = 'end'; test = t;} )(test);
alert(test) //alerts 'test'
```

Or

```
var myObject = {test: "start"};
var myFunc = function (theObject){
    theObject.test = 'end';
}(myObject);
alert(myObject.test);
```